# Define puppet attributes used in init.pp inherited in other classes

Tags: puppet

I'd like to force the content of other classes to be use a single definition, rather than repeating the same code in each of my classes, what is the correct way of doing this? For example (this is psuedo code, so my apologies for syntax)...

```
class example::code1 (
   $my_password = 'password',
)

class example::code2 (
   $my_password = 'password',
)
```

What I'd like is to just have an init.pp file containing my_password which will be inherited by all the other classes. If this is possible, what should I put in the existing classes? If I define this in init.pp will the values get overwritten when used in other classes or do they need to reference the init.pp file somehow? My apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm quite new to puppet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Puppet and SO then.

There are multiple ways to supply your nodes with data.

1. If you use an ENC such as Puppet Dashboard, you can assign values there.
2. Hiera is the recommended way of assigning data.
3. You can put the variable assignment on the global scope, outside any class.
4. You can include a class and use values declared therein

e.g.

```
class config {
  $password = 'foo'
}
```

and use it like

```
class something {
  include config
  $pw = $config::password
}
```

There may be other alternatives. You should probably look at [Hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/) first.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! I may look at Hiera at a later point; it looks somewhat confusing. The method you've provided looks spot on though :D

Comment: Glad that helped. You may wish to accept the answer if it works for you *hint hint* ;)